# How to run function separately for each tag of a vue.js app?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2

I'm discovering Vue JS and I'd like to try something, looking at the code will be easier to understand before an explanation.

https://jsfiddle.net/n4mav0x8/2/

As you can see, there are two tags (`[% message %]`), what I want to do is to show a random color for each of the tag from the list, is it possible ?

**html:**

```
<div id="app-5">

  <div class="color">
    <span class="colorHandler">
      <p>[% message %]</p>
    </span>
  </div>

  <div class="color">
    <span class="colorHandler">
      <p>[% message %]</p>
    </span>
  </div>

  ... # the quantity of these specific '[% message %]' tags may vary.
</div>
```

**javascript (VueJs) :**

```
var colors = "['#e6f0ff', '#000a1a' ,'#ffe680', '#ffcc00', '#ffd9b3']";
var parsed_colors = colors.match(/#[a-f0-9]{6}/g);
var randomIndex = Math.floor(Math.random() * parsed_colors.length); 
var randomElement = parsed_colors[randomIndex];

var app5 = new Vue({
  el: '#app-5',
  data: {
    message: randomElement
  },
  delimiters: ["[%","%]"]
})
```

How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[use methods](https://jsfiddle.net/Lsc7hggs/) (but you may need to refresh as values are sometimes randomly same :) )

```
var app5 = new Vue({
  el: '#app-5',
  data: {
    message: null
  },
  methods:{
    randomColor:function(){
        var colors = "['#e6f0ff', '#000a1a' ,'#ffe680', '#ffcc00', '#ffd9b3']";
      var parsed_colors = colors.match(/#[a-f0-9]{6}/g);
      var randomIndex = Math.floor(Math.random() * parsed_colors.length); 
      var randomElement = parsed_colors[randomIndex];
      return randomElement
    }
  },
  delimiters: ["[%","%]"]
})
```

Comment: I see, how can I show it on the template ? I tried here : https://jsfiddle.net/n4mav0x8/4/

Comment: I've added fiddle above: [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Lsc7hggs/) - just put calls to method instead of data properties - <p>[% randomColor() %]</p>